# If a class has an inner class and the inner class runs a thread, do the inner class threads share the same fields of the outer class with one another?

Tags: java, multithreading, inner-classes, runnable

Basically, if I have the code:

```
public class Outer { 
   public int counter = 0;
   public void makeNewThread() {
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Inner());
      t1.start();
   }

   private class Inner implements Runnable {
      public void run() { //do stuff involving counter... }
   }

}
```

Everytime makeNewThread() is called, will each thread have their own version of counter, or will they all share the same version of counter? I would assume they would all share the same version since it's an inner class, but each thread has their own stack so I'm not sure.

Comment: Same instance of `Outer` is shared; ***unless*** you instantiate multiple instances of `Outer`. Modifying `counter` without `volatile` (or using an `AtomicInteger`) is not advisable. But then "do stuff involving counter" might, or might not, be done in a safe manner.

Comment: volatile is usually not enough for counters. One gets concurrency problem incrementing the value like "counter = counter + 1" from different threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will share the same `counter`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a single instance of Outer, you will have only a single instance of counter. All the threads will share it.

Important! Validate concurrency and visibility issues accessing the counter from different threads. Most probably you need to use AtomicInteger instead of "int" or wrap all the access code (for both write and read operations) into a synchronize block.

Comment: I wanted to read, increment, and decrement counter, so I made it volatile and I wrapped them in a synchronized method i.e. `public synchronized int getCounter() {return count; }` and `public synchronized void incrementCount() {count++}`. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it will work. It is even a bit more, than sufficient :-) If the field is volatile, you don't need to synchronize the getter. And both methods (getter and setter) must be methods of the class Outer, not Inner.

Comment: Take a look on AtomicInteger. It is simpler and much faster way to increment multithread counter.